# Graphics Crad drivers for Radeon 7000

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I am knew to Ubuntu but love the OS and have been installing it on my PC systems at home.

I have an old computer which I am currently using which has the following graphics card. I am unable tot find the drivers anywhere and have searched forums and the ATI website. I wonder if anyone could help me as currently ubuntu runs faultlessly on the PC but there is horrible lag on the graphics.

Many thanks for all help in advance,

Andy

Graphics card: AMD ATI RV100 Radeon 7000/Radeon VE

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1302084) on AMD Developer Central, this card is too old to be  supported by the proprietary fglrx driver.

Also, it's not suggested to download the driver provided on AMD website.

Therefore I think the only working driver is the open-source one.

If you're having graphical performance issue, you could:

1. Try older LTS version (e.g. 12.04, but I doubt it will help in this case.)
2. Select a light-weighted flavor Ubuntu like [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), which needs less graphical power.

More information from [RadeonDriver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) on help.ubuntu.com:

> ### Supported, but Hardware is Too Old for Unity
>
> These cards will not run Ubuntu's Unity desktop with 3D acceleration. They will still run Unity, but the CPU will be used for basic drawing and performance may suffer. If you have one of these cards, a lighter desktop (such as xfce or lxde, found in Xubuntu and Lubuntu respectively) is recommended. 
>   ...
>   R100                     Radeon 7200 
>   **RV100                    Radeon 7000(VE), M6, RN50/ES1000 (2D only)**
>
>   RS100                    Radeon IGP320(M)
>   ...

Comment: How would I download and install the open-source one?

Comment: It's called "radeon" and already included in your kernel.